# Sorting array from vuex store (infinite render warning)

Tags: vue.js

I'm retrieving an array of objects from the vuex store and I am trying to sort that array in one of my components (I don't want to sort the array in the store). But I get an error `infinite update loop in a component render function` in my browser. What is happening here and how can I fix this?

```
<template>
  <div
    v-for="(item, i) in itemList">
    {{item.description}}
  </div>
</template>


computed: Object.assign({},
  mapGetters({
    currentItemList: "item/current",
  }),
  {
   itemList() {
     if(this.currentItemList != undefined) {
       return this.currentItemList.sort(function(a, b) {
           var textA = a.description.toUpperCase()
           var textB = b.description.toUpperCase()
           return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0
         })
      }
      else {
        return []
      }
    },
  }
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sort` will mutate the array in place. You can create a local copy of the item list in your component and then sort the copy to avoid the side effect:

```js
itemList() {
  if(this.currentItemList != undefined) {
    var localItemList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.currentItemList))
    return localItemList.sort(...)
```

Comment: Jns' solution with `Array.prototype.slice()` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)) is not just _much faster_ than encoding and parsing an object to and from JSON, it also is widely more supported.

Answer (score 7):

With `this.currentItemList.sort` you are mutating reactive data in computed properties - that will trigger the component always to rerender ... Do not mutate data in computed properties. Instead make sure to sort on a copy of your array: `this.currentItemList.slice().sort(...)`